# I'm new to this i need some help i want to add a if a number is negative it should print some sort of warning and make them type it again

Tags: java, do-while

I need some help i want to add some sort of warning when i enter a negative number and make me type it again but i dont know how to do it.

```
public class SR {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println("The square root of " + n + " is: " + squareRoot(n));
  }

  public static double squareRoot(int num) {
    double t;
    double sqrtroot = num / 2;
    do {
      t = sqrtroot;
      sqrtroot = (t + (num / t)) / 2;
    } while ((t - sqrtroot) != 0);
    return sqrtroot;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, you tagged the question with do-while so you must have some clue what you should do

Answer (score 0):

You could use a do-while loop to continuously ask for input until you get a positive number. E.g.:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = -1;
do {
    System.out.print("Enter a positive number: ");
    n = sc.nextInt();
} while (n <= 0);
```